# Linearly independence after feature embedding

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

## Problem

If feature vectors $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_m$ are linearly independent, argue whether or not their embedding $\psi(\mathbf{x}_1), \psi(\mathbf{x}_2),\cdots,\psi(\mathbf{x}_m)$ are linearly independent.

## Some Thoughts

The complication here is that the choice of $\psi(\cdot)$ is *not* random and often requires that the resulting $\psi(\mathbf{x}_i)$'s being linearly separable (or we could always do $\psi:\mathbf{x}_i\mapsto \mathbf{0}$, but this is hardly useful). I am wondering whether this requirement could guarantee that the mapping keeps the linearly independence of original vectors $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_m$.

Comment: Could you tell us more precisely what you mean by _"requires that the resulting $\psi(\mathbf{x}_i)$'s being linearly separable"_?

Comment: @Federico My bad. Suppose $\mathbf{x}_i$'s belongs to two classes, then in original space they are not separable by a hyperplane. But after transformation, i.e. $\psi(\mathbf{x}_i)$'s, they could be separated by a hyperplane.

Comment: Well then it's even more severe that what I wrote. For example, all points from the first class could be mapped to the same vector $v$ and all points from the second class to another vector $w$. From the point of view of machine learning, this is quite a perfect situation, but for sure the images are not linearly independent.

Comment: It seems to me that the linear independence of the images is not really relevant for the purpose of ML, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Federico Thank you. I think your example is sufficient for my purpose. Since polynomial and RBF mapping are often used, I have always been struggling with these more complicated mappings but ignore the most straightforward case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by *"requires that the resulting $\psi(\mathbf{x}_i)$'s being linearly separable"*. If you mean that any of the points $\psi(\mathbf{x}_i)$ can be linearly separated from the others, then the answer is false.

For instance, the points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are linearly separable in this sense, but are not linearly independent.